# Error using matplotlib.figure vs pylab when using ginput

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to get user selected points (to get a polygon) from an image. I have already embedded a matplotlib.figure in a lot of my code, so I would MUCH prefer to use this style over pylab's figure. I am trying to do the follow:

```
import pylab
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

x1 = pylab.rand(103, 53) 
figure = Figure(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=100)
axes = figure.add_subplot(111)
axes.imshow(x1) 
x = figure.ginput(2) 

print(x)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ginput_demo.py", line 17, in <module>
    x = figure.ginput(2)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1177, in ginpu
t
    show_clicks=show_clicks)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\blocking_input.py", line 282, i
n __call__
    BlockingInput.__call__(self,n=n,timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\blocking_input.py", line 94, in
 __call__
    self.fig.show()
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'show'
```

The original pylab code that works that I am trying to more or less reproduce is from [here](http://old.nabble.com/using-ginput-with-images----axes-are-resized--td20270943.html):

```
import pylab 

x1 = pylab.rand(103, 53) 
fig1 = pylab.figure(1) 
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111) 
ax1.imshow(x1) 
ax1.axis('image') 
ax1.axis('off') 
x = fig1.ginput(2) 

fig1.show()
```

So basically, is there a way to get pylab.ginput to work with a matplotlib.figure or matplotlib.axes reference??

Thanks,

tylerthemiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `pylab.ginput` instead of `myfigure.ginput`.
After changing this, you will realize that `axes.imshow` is not plotting, you can fix it using `pylab.imshow`.
And finally you will find that after clicking and getting the position numbers, the figure disappears, so you want to add a `pylab.show` at the end.

This works, trying to follow as close as possible your prefered way of coding mpl:

```
from pylab import show, ginput, rand, imshow
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

x1 = rand(103, 53) 
figure = Figure(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=100)
axes = figure.add_subplot(111)

imshow(x1)
x = ginput(2) 
print(x)
show()
```

I think the problem here comes from mixing different modules (coding styles) from matplotlib.
Your `myfigure.ginput()` complaints about its Figure class not having a `show` method. However it works with `pylab.figure.ginput()`.
In fact, `pylab.figure`, that is actually the one defined in the pyplot module:

```
>>> import pylab
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
>>> pylab.figure is plt.figure
True
```

although being of the class `matplotlib.figure.Figure` is not the same as the Figure instance

```
myfigure = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
```

`pyplot.figure` implements a couple of additional methods, one of them `show()`:

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot
>>> from matplotlib.figure import Figure
>>> pfig = set(dir(pyplot.figure()))
>>> Ffig = set(dir(Figure()))
>>> pfig.difference(Ffig)
set(['number', 'show'])
```

that's why you got the `AttributeError` with the `Figure` instance.

Comment: Thanks! This solves my basic problem. However, I don't know how to implement it in my specific case. Edited question above.

Comment: If this solves your basic problem you should select the answer. Otherwise, how could I be sure that, if I take the time to answer this second question, you are not going to extend the question indefinitely instead of selecting it?

Comment: Done, lemme know if you have time to help me with the second part of my question. If not, I will post it in a separate question to get new help :)

Comment: @tylerthemiler fair enough, I will try in a few hours, but the best thing, imho, would be to let your question as it was and, with the info you got from here already implemented, to open a new, specific one.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the suggested solution to work properly when using an embedded plot in a GUI (Pyqt4) - my quick&dirty working solution was to put a Try/Catch into blocking_input.py. 
Note -this would probably be overwritten when you update matplotlib so you may want to save associations using unique name(s)

```
 # TRY TO "Ensure that the figure is shown" in the standard way
    try:
        self.fig.show()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```